# How to prove fl(x^k) definition

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, machine-precision

How would I show that 
fl(x^k)= (x^k)(1 + δ)^(k−1), 
where |δ| ≤ ,ε if x is a floating-point machine number in a
computer that has machine precision .

Edit: I was thinking I can use induction to prove this.

Comment: Induction seems like a sensible way to go. I'm guessing know that $\operatorname{fl}(x \times y) = (x \times y)(1 + \delta)$ for some $|\delta| \le \varepsilon$. Just be careful not to assume the $\delta$s are the same at each step.

Comment: why is δ not that same? Im not that good with induction proofs. Can you elaborate on how the proof will go.

Comment: I was hoping someone else might answer for me, since I don't actually know anything about floating point arithmetic, and for the above comment, I just looked online and found [these lecture slides](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/csci5304/FILES/LecN3.pdf). It seems weird to me, because now that I think about it, induction isn't necessary with the above assumption, and for some reasons that are hard to articulate, I feel that it should be. Do you have some more context for the problem? Maybe you could include some results relevant to floating point multiplication?